# adding ids, and classes to an image tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails image tag"

```
<%= image_tag 'how-it-works.png', {id: 'how-it-works'} %>
```

I would also like to add the bootstrap class `img-responsive` so the image stays within its container.

How would one do it?

I see a few option on the rails docs but none of them seem to be working:

```
image_tag("icon")
# => <img alt="Icon" src="/assets/icon" />
image_tag("icon.png")
# => <img alt="Icon" src="/assets/icon.png" />
image_tag("icon.png", size: "16x10", alt: "Edit Entry")
# => <img src="/assets/icon.png" width="16" height="10" alt="Edit Entry" />
image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", size: "16")
# => <img src="/icons/icon.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Icon" />
image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", height: '32', width: '32')
# => <img alt="Icon" height="32" src="/icons/icon.gif" width="32" />
image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", class: "menu_icon")
# => <img alt="Icon" class="menu_icon" src="/icons/icon.gif" />
image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", data: { title: 'Rails Application' })
# => <img data-title="Rails Application" src="/icons/icon.gif" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> image_tag(source, options = {})

The `source` is the name of your image file in the `assets/images` directory, so, you can pass the `id` and `class` as options. No need to use brackets (6th example):

```
<%= image_tag 'how-it-works.png', id: 'how-it-works', class: 'img-responsive' %>
```

Which renders:

```
<img id="how-it-works" class="img-responsive" src="/assets/how-it-works-....png" alt="How it works">
```